# Differentiation by substituting trig functions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So I have this question:

> If $$\sqrt{1-x^6} + \sqrt{1-y^6}=a^3(x^3-y^3)$$
> Prove that:
> $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x^2}{y^2}\sqrt {\frac{1-y^6}{1-x^6}}$$

I searched up some solutions and in all of them , they substitute $x^3$ with $\sin(k)$ and $y^3$ with some other $\sin(l)$.

P.S - Yes, the square is over the entire term, sorry not still a latex expert

Why do they do this? also is there any method where you dont use that specefic technique to solve this problem?

Comment: They used that to deal with expressions of the form $\sqrt{1-m^{2n}}$.

Comment: Suppose $a \geq 0$, so for $\sqrt{1-a}$ to be defined in real numbers, we need $a \leq 1$. So $a$ is a real number that lies in $[0,1]$. Now think about the range of values taken by $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$.

Comment: but sin and cos go from [-1,1] right?

Comment: @MrKhonsu I have edited the comment/.

Comment: ohh right thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^3=\sin A, y^3=\sin B$, then
we get $$\cos A+\cos B=a^3(\sin A- \sin B)\implies 2 \cos[(A+B)/2] \cos [(A-B)/2]$$ $$=a^2 2 \cos[(A+B)/2] \sin[(A-B)/2] \implies \cot[(A-B)/2]=a^2$$
$$\implies (A-B)=2 \cot^{-1} a^2$$
D.w.r.t. $x$ we get
$$\frac{dA}{dx}=\frac{dB}{dx} \implies \frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^6}}=\frac{3y^2}{\sqrt{1-y^6}} \frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{y^2}\frac{\sqrt{1-y^6}}{\sqrt{1-x^6}}$$